# C# application to hide a terminal window, terminal not launched when app set to start at logon

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics

I'm working on an application in C# that should start a process in the command prompt window, but hide the window, when the user logs on.

At this point, the application is configured to launch on a Terminal Server when users log on.  The application starts, but the process in the command prompt fails to launch (I can tell by looking at the task manager).  If I end-task on the application and start it by double-clicking the application itself, it starts the process hidden as I expect.

Any ideas why it won't work if launch as part of a logon script, but will if I launch it manually?

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + LaunchCommand);
procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
process.Start();

//Where LaunchCommand contains C:\MyService.exe
```

Comment: Does it work if you set procStartInfo.LoadUserProfile  to true ? If not can you log the StandardError output (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx) and post it here ?

Answer (score 0):

This outputs the data to Visual Studios command window, try using

```
Console.[the command]
```